# How to rectify the key definition in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While pressing the "**alt(cmd)** + **UP**" keys in Visual Studio Code on MacBook, the cursor can move to the top of the editing area.

But when pressing the "**alt(cmd)** + **DOWN**" keys, the editor shows "**No definition found**" as the following picture showed.

[image]
What to do to make "**alt(cmd)** + **DOWN**" keys can move the cursor to the bottom of the editing area?

If I post at the wrong place, please let me know where to post it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the keybinding can be changed via "**File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts**", then key in the keywords to change the keybinding for a specific command.

[image]

E.g. I can key in "cmd+down" or "definition" to find out the keybinding and click the "pencil" icon to change. (I've changed the keybinding as follows.)

[image]